# Why can I call all these methods that aren't explicitly defined in a class?

Tags: python, oop, methods, vk

So I am working with an [API wrapper](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/master/vk/api.py) in python for vk, Europe's Facebook equivalent. The documentation on the [vk site](https://vk.com/dev/methods) has all the API calls that can be used, and the wrapper is able to call them correctly. For example, to get a user's information, you would call `api.users.get(id)` to get a user by id. My question is this: how can the wrapper correctly handle such a call when neither `users` or a corresponding `users.get()` method is defined inside the `api` object?

I know it involves the `__getattr__()` and `__call__()` methods, but I can't find any good documentation on how to use them in this way.

EDIT

the `api` object is instantiated via `api = vk.API(id, email, password)`

Comment: What is `api` an instance of?

Comment: @IanAuld I'm not entirely sure. I have `api = vk.API(id, email, password)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through this together, shall we?

## `api`

To execute `api.users.get()`, Python first has to know `api`. And due to your instantiation, it *does* know it: It's a local variable holding an instance of [`APISession`](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L50).

## `api.users`

Then, it has to know `api.users`. Python first looks at the members of the `api` instance, at the members of its class (`APISession`) and at the members of that class' super-classes (only `object` in the case of `APISession`). Failing to find a member called `users` in any of these places, it looks for a member function called `__getattr__` in those same places. It will find it right on the instance, because `APISession` [has an (instance) member function of this name](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L141).

Python then calls it with `'users'` (the name of the so-far missing member) and uses the function's return value as if it were that member. So

```
api.users
```

is equivalent to

```
api.__getattr__('users')
```

Let's see [what that returns](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L142).

```
    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return APIMethod(self, method_name)
```

Oh. So

```
api.users # via api.__getattr__('users')
```

is equivalent to

```
APIMethod(api, 'users')
```

creating a new [`APIMethod`](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L217) instance.

`api` and `'users'` [end up](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L220) as that instance's `_api_session` and `_method_name` members. Makes sense, I guess.

## `api.users.get`

Python still hasn't executed our statement. It needs to know `api.users.get()` to do so. The same game as before repeats, just in the `api.users` object instead of the `api` object this time: No member method `get()` and no member `get` is found on the `APIMethod` instance `api.users` points to, nor on its class or superclasses, so Python turns to the `__getattr__` method, which for this class does something peculiar:

```
    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return APIMethod(self._api_session, self._method_name + '.' + method_name)
```

A new instance of the same class! Let's plug in the instance members of `api.users`, and

```
api.users.get
```

becomes equivalent to

```
APIMethod(api, 'users' + '.' + 'get')
```

So we will have the `api` object also in `api.user.get`'s `_apisession` and the string `'users.get'` in its `_method_name`.

## `api.users.get()` (note the `()`)

So `api.users.get` is an object. To call it, Python has to pretend it's a function, or more specifically, a method of `api.users`. It does so, by instead calling `api.users.get`'s [`__call__` method](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L227), which looks like this:

```
    def __call__(self, **method_kwargs):
        return self._api_session(self._method_name, **method_kwargs)
```

Let's work this out:

```
api.users.get()
# is equivalent to
api.users.get.__call__() # no arguments, because we passed none to `get()`
# will return
api.users.get._api_session(api.users.get._method_name)
# which is
api('users.get')
```

So now Python is calling the `api` object as if it were a function. `__call__` to the rescue, once more, [this time](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L144) looking like this:

```
    def __call__(self, method_name, **method_kwargs):
        response = self.method_request(method_name, **method_kwargs)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # there are may be 2 dicts in 1 json
        # for example: {'error': ...}{'response': ...}
        errors = []
        error_codes = []
        for data in json_iter_parse(response.text):
            if 'error' in data:
                error_data = data['error']
                if error_data['error_code'] == CAPTCHA_IS_NEEDED:
                    return self.captcha_is_needed(error_data, method_name, **method_kwargs)

                error_codes.append(error_data['error_code'])
                errors.append(error_data)

            if 'response' in data:
                for error in errors:
                    warnings.warn(str(error))

                return data['response']

        if AUTHORIZATION_FAILED in error_codes:  # invalid access token
            self.access_token = None
            self.get_access_token()
            return self(method_name, **method_kwargs)
        else:
            raise VkAPIMethodError(errors[0])
```

Now, that's a lot of error handling. For this analysis, I'm only interested in the happy path. I'm only interested in the happy path's result (and how we got there). So lets start [at the result](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L165).

```
return data['response']
```

Where did `data` come from? It's the first element of `response.text` interpreted as JSON that does contain a 'response' object. So it seems that from the `response` object we got, we're extracting the *actual* response part.

Where did the `response` object come from? It [was returned](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L165) by

```
api.method_request('users.get')
```

Which, for all we care, is a plain [normal method](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py#L174) call that doesn't require any fancy fallbacks. (Its implementation of course, on some levels, might.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the comments are correct, and `api` is an instance of `APISession` as defined in [this particular commit](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/43671ff3f71f87eb6ac53ad6e3a44e8965be4a17/vk/api.py), then this is a bit of an interesting maze:

So first you want to access `api.user`. `APISession` has no such attribute, so it calls `__getattr__('user')` instead, which is defined as:

```
def __getattr__(self, method_name):
    return APIMethod(self, method_name)
```

So this constructs an `APIMethod(api,'user')`. Now you want to call the method `get` on the  `APIMethod(api,'user')` that is bound to `api.users`, but an `APIMethod` doesn't have a `get` method, so it calls its own `__getattr__('get')` to figure out what to do:

```
def __getattr__(self, method_name):
    return APIMethod(self._api_session, self._method_name + '.' + method_name)
```

This returns a `APIMethod(api,'users.get')` which is then called, invoking the `__call__` method of the `APIMethod` class, which is:

```
def __call__(self, **method_kwargs):
    return self._api_session(self._method_name, **method_kwargs)
```

So this tries to return `api('users.get')`, but `api` is an `APISession` object, so it invokes the `__call__` method of this class, defined as (stripping out the error handling for simplicity):

```
def __call__(self, method_name, **method_kwargs):
    response = self.method_request(method_name, **method_kwargs)
    response.raise_for_status()

    for data in json_iter_parse(response.text):
        if 'response' in data:
            return data['response']
```

So it then calls a method_request('users.get'), which if you follow that method actually does a POST request, and some data comes back as a response, which is then returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `users.get()` has nothing to do with the `api` object. As for the `users`, you are right, if there is no such member defined, then there is certainly some logic inside the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__). So as you can see in the documentation `__getattr__` is...

> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self). name is the attribute name.

So exactly, as there is no `users` defined for the `api`'s class, then the `__getattr__` is being called with `'users'` passed as the `name` parameter. Then, most probably dynamically, depending on the passed parameter, an object is being constructed for the `users` component and returned, which will be responsible to define or handle in similar way the `get()` method.

To get the whole idea, try the following:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

        self.defined_one = 'I am defined inside A'

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('getting attribute {}'.format(item))

        return 'I am ' + item


a = A()

>>> print(a.some_item)  # this will call __getattr__ as some_item is not defined
getting attribute some_item
I am some_item
>>> print(a.and_another_one)  # this will call __getattr__ as and_another_one is not defined
getting attribute and_another_one
I am and_another_one
>>> print(a.defined_one)  # this will NOT call __getattr__ as defined_one is defined in A
I am defined inside A
```